# No text parsed from document

Tags: python, pandas

I have written an html text parser, when I use it in a large batch of files i.e. 5,000 or more, it randomly produces this error, when I re-run it it produces the same error in the exact same files. So I removed those files and parsed them individually and the parser read them.

So I created a new folder with the "Problematic" files and tried parsing them separately, it produced no error for most then it re-produced the same error again.

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
import glob

source_file = r'C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/Desktop/Mar/Problematic/'

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_file,"*.html"))

for file_name in file_names:
    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
    print (table)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\No Text Parsed Troubleshooting\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 735, in _build_doc
    raise XMLSyntaxError("no text parsed from document", 0, 0, 0)
  File "<string>", line 0
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: no text parsed from document

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I took the "unreadable" files outside of the folder and parsed them individually and the code read them, I can't seem to identify what is wrong.

I hope my explanation is clear and sufficient.

Comment: before `print(table)`, add `print(file_name)` to see which file is causing the problem. then add the content of the file to your question

Comment: There is one line in the error that says `no text parsed from document`, you might want to check the file is there is any data in it or not and as suggested by @AvenDesta. create a `try/except` block and print the name of the file in the `except`

Comment: @AvenDesta I have identified the file(s) and when I run them through the program individually they work, I'm not sure what the problem is. If it can read it individually why doesn't it read when placed in a folder? The file contains 100+ tables, I can't exactly post it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden .DS_STORE file in the folder. This is my code:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import os
from time import sleep

locations_folder = '/Users/jerryhu/Documents/Documents/Zenly/locations'
failed_files = []

def parse(file):
    tables = pd.read_html(file)
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(tables[0])

    path, name = os.path.split(file)

    with open(f'/Users/jerryhu/Documents/Documents/Zenly/locations_csv/{name}'.replace('.html', '.csv'), 'w') as writeCSV:
        dataframe.to_csv(writeCSV)
        print(f"Writing {name.replace('.html', '.csv')} to disk")

        try:
            failed_files.remove(file)
        except:
            pass

for filename in os.listdir(locations_folder):
    file = os.path.join(locations_folder, filename)

    if os.path.exists(file):
        try:
            parse(file)
        except:
            failed_files.append(file)


print("\nFinished. These files failed to parse:")
for i in failed_files:
    print(i)

print("Retrying in 3 seconds.")
sleep(3)

for i in failed_files:
    try:
        parse(i)
    except:
        print(f'{i} couldn\'t be parsed.')
```

This is the error returned:

```
Writing 2022-10-09.csv to disk
Writing 2022-09-13.csv to disk
Writing 2022-09-05.csv to disk
Writing 2022-08-28.csv to disk
Writing 2022-12-22.csv to disk
Writing 2022-08-08.csv to disk
Writing 2023-01-01.csv to disk
Writing 2022-09-25.csv to disk
Writing 2022-12-02.csv to disk
Writing 2022-11-12.csv to disk
Writing 2022-12-14.csv to disk
Writing 2022-10-29.csv to disk
Writing 2022-11-04.csv to disk
Writing 2022-10-05.csv to disk
Writing 2022-11-28.csv to disk
Writing 2022-08-24.csv to disk
Writing 2022-07-17.csv to disk
Writing 2022-09-09.csv to disk
Writing 2022-10-13.csv to disk

Finished. These files failed to parse:
/Users/jerryhu/Documents/Documents/Zenly/locations/.DS_Store
Retrying in 3 seconds.
/Users/jerryhu/Documents/Documents/Zenly/locations/.DS_Store couldn't be parsed.
```

Just put a try and except block to skip the DS_Store file.

Comment: Don't use bare except blocks. You know the error(s) that you want to catch, so specify those errors